# Error: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined, Calling parent Method in Child

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js, reactjs

I am rendering a chart in parent component. When I am trying to access this.props.onUpdate() in child component, getting an error "Cannot read property 'props' of undefined"
I have to update chart data acc to start and end time.
Child component

```
var React = require('React');
var ReactDOM = require('ReactDOM');
var Chart = require('react-google-charts').Chart;
var $ = require('jquery');

var LChart = React.createClass({
   getInitialState: function() {
       return {
            rows: [],            
               }
        },
    componentWillMount: function () {
        var _this = this;
            var request = function () {
                this.props.onUpdate();
                $.post("/url" ,{'start':this.props.sTime, 'end':this.props.eTime }, function (result) { 

                    _this.setState({
                        rows: result.data
                    });
                });
               setTimeout(request, 10000);
            };
         request();
        },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div id="chart_widget" >
                <Chart chartType="LineChart"
                   rows={this.state.rows}
                   columns={this.props.columns}
                   options={this.props.options}
                   width={this.props.width}
                   height={this.props.height} />
            </div>
        );
      }
    });
module.exports = LChart;
```

parent component:

```
var React = require('React');
var LChart = require('LChart');

var Parent = React.createClass({    

 getInitialState: function()
  {
      return ({
          columns: [
                {
                    'type': 'datetime',
                    'label' : 'Date'
                },
                {
                    'type' : 'number',
                    'label' : Val
                }
                ],
          options: 
                {
                    hAxis:{format:'HH:mm'},
                },
          date: new Date(),
          eTime: date.getTime(),
          sTime: eTime - (60000 * 5),
      });
  },
  onUpdate: function(val){
      this.setState({
          date: new Date(),
          eTime: date.getTime(),
          sTime: eTime - (60000 * range),
      });
  },
render: function () {
    return (
            <div >
                <LChart width="500px" height="400px" 
                             date={this.state.date} 
                             sTime={this.state.sTime} 
                             eTime={this.state.eTime}
                             columns={this.state.columns}
                             options={this.state.options}
                             onUpdate={this.onUpdate}/>
            </div>  
        );
    }
}); 
module.exports = Parent;
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `_this.props.onUpdate()`, with the underscore?

Comment: `this` cannot be undefined in any scenario.

Comment: Can you tell us where the error is happening?

Comment: @Andrew Error is happening in child component at line 15 this.props.onUpdate()

Comment: @WanderNauta When I am using _this.props.onUpdate(). This error is gone. I am getting another error. In parent component its saying date is not define. Cant we use date like this in setState function, where endTime will calculated on the basis of date. this.setState({
          date: new Date(),
          eTime: date.getTime(),
          sTime: eTime - (60000 * range),
      });

Comment: @user2194838 Regarding your setState issue, declare the new Date outside of the setState call: `onUpdate: function(val){  var date = new Date();  this.setState({ eTime: date.getTime(), sTime: eTime - (60000 * range)});   }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind your `request` to `LChart` component.

```
var LChart = React.createClass({
   getInitialState: function() {
       return {
            rows: [],            
               }
        },
    componentWillMount: function () {
        var _this = this;
            var request = function () {
                this.props.onUpdate();
                $.post("/url" ,{'start':this.props.sTime, 'end':this.props.eTime }, function (result) { 

                    _this.setState({
                        rows: result.data
                    });
                });
               setTimeout(request, 10000);
            };
         request = request.bind(this);
         request();
        },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div id="chart_widget" >
                <Chart chartType="LineChart"
                   rows={this.state.rows}
                   columns={this.props.columns}
                   options={this.props.options}
                   width={this.props.width}
                   height={this.props.height} />
            </div>
        );
      }
});
```

Besides, in your parent components, declare the `new Date` outside of the `setState` call.